# set computer to ignore RST packets on Chromebook

Tags: chromebook

My rental server doesn't allow me to remote on via SSH, despite assuring me that everything is setup. How do I override RST packets on a Chromebook without using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to drop TCP reset packets.

[This blog post](http://www.dereckson.be/blog/2015/01/15/chromebook-run-a-ssh-server-on-chrome-os/) explains how to get a root shell and add an iptables rule.

Instead of the rule given in the article to get SSH access, try this rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST -j DROP
```

(Disclaimer: I don't know anything about chromebooks except that they run Linux.)